# SonarLint 3.0 fails in connecting remote sonarqube 6.5 in intellij

Tags: ssl, sonarqube, sonarlint-intellij

I have installed the sonar lint plugin in intelliJ and trying to connect to remote sonarQube by configuring the url, username and password. Connection is failed. After seeing the intellij logs caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host not verified. I have searched over and tried many options:

1. Configured the certificate in jvm keystore
2. Updated the intellij preferences for server certificates to accept the non trusted certificates
   3.Tried configuring the idea.vmoptions with following properties

   -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake
   -Djavax.net.debug=all

But nothing is working. Can some help in testing the connection? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you connect to SonarQube using a browser? Did you check if the certificate is not expired?

Comment: I can connect from browser. We don't have public certificate. Thanks for response